# Returning user score based on an action using Returns and Print

Tags: python

I am trying to create an action game where the user is prompted with 3 options, when the user selects a specific action for instance drinking would add 10 points to the first and second score, I tried returning the user input and calculating it, however, I keep getting the same number 410 when I enter the drinking action the score does not increase, for this question I must use a return. Can someone help?

```
def main():
    userStat1 = 400
    userStat2 = 400
        
    for tries in range(3):
        
        def userQ():
            asking = input ("Enter drink, run, jump: ")

            def userScore():
                if userAsk== "drink":
                    userStat1 + 10
                    userStat2 + 10
                    print (userStat1, userStat2)
                    return userStat1 and userStat2
                if userAsk== "run":
                    userStat1 + 60
                    userStat2 +50
                    print (userStat1, userStat2)
                    return userStat1 and userStat2
                if userAsk== "jump":
                    userStat1 + 30
                    userStat2 + 40
                    print (userStat1, userStat2)
                    return userStat1 and userStat2

                print ("your final score is", userStat, userStat2)
            userScore()

            return asking


        askingUser()


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `userStat+10`. You must do `userStat+=10` which is short form for `userStat=userStat+10`

Comment: I did fix this however, it still does not return the value added.

Comment: I relooked your code. Perhaps you can simply return the userStats and updating them outside the function if you really have to use the return function. In fact I see no use in the return function there.